# Show that $HKCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a parallellogram such that $\angle DAB \gt 90º$. Let $H$ be a point on $AD$ such that $BH \mathbin \bot AD$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Let $K$ be the intersection of $DM$ with the circumcircle of $ADB$. Show that $HKCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Form the rectangle AHBX (which should automatically be cyclic).

[image]

(2) Prove that HXCD is cyclic.

(3) Prove that MKBX is cyclic.

(4) Prove that HKXD is cyclic.

Result follows from (2) and (4).

---

Added

> (Wrong version, please ignore)
>
> After proving HXCD is cyclic, we have $\phi’’ = \phi’$. In the green circle, $\phi = \phi’$. $\phi’’ = \phi$ implies MKBX is cyclic.
>
> (Corrected version)
>
> In the green circle, $\phi = \phi’$.
>
> Note that $\angle KBX = \phi + \theta’ = \phi’ + \theta = \omega$, the exterior angle of $\triangle HMD$. This means KBXM is cyclic because the exterior angle of the to-be-cyclic quadrilateral = its interior opposite angle.
>
> Then, $\phi’’ = \phi =\phi’$. Therefore, HKXD is also cyclic.

Comment: How do you prove $MKBX$ is cyclic? I understand how everything follows from there.

Comment: @problembuster See added.

Comment: Isn´t supposing that is the same as supposing that $K$ belongs to the circumcircle of $HKCD$ since $\angle HXK = \phi´´$?

Comment: Besides, wouldn´t $\phi’’ = \phi’$ imply that $HKXD$ is cyclic with no need to prove $MKBX$ is?

Comment: @problembuster Sorry for giving the reversed answer. See the corrected version.